# Error in MP-androidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Following is the error I'm getting while my app is cleared by system cache.
Whenever I switch between apps i get this error.
so if any of u have the knowledge of this error or MPandroidchart library.
Please help.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 
11-09 19:34:42.397 E/AndroidRuntime( 5201):     at             
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
11-09 19:34:42.397 E/AndroidRuntime( 5201):     at 
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
11- 09 19:34:42.397 E/AndroidRuntime( 5201):    at 
com.github.mikephil.charting.data.DataSet.getEntryForIndex(DataSet.java:286)
11-09 19:34:42.397 E/AndroidRuntime( 5201):     at
```

Following is the code for drawing Data on Line Chart
i have tried a lot from google and GIt also but couldnt found any solution

```
    public void setData()
{
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
    mChart.fitScreen();
    Description description = mChart.getDescription();
    description.setText("");
    setLineChartData();
    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            Log.d("VALUESSS>>",value+"");
  //                arrayListDate
            return mMonths[(int) value % mMonths.length];
        }
    });
}
private ArrayList<Entry> setYAxisValues(){
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<SplashScreen.arrayListPrice.size();i++)
    {
        yVals.add(new Entry(i, SplashScreen.arrayListPrice.get(i)));
    }
    return yVals;
}
private void setLineChartData() {
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = setYAxisValues();
    // create a dataset and give it a type

    set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "Zenith Bitcoin");
    set1.setFillAlpha(110);
    set1.setFillColor(Color.RED);
    set1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#1caf9a"));
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE);
    set1.setLineWidth(0.5f);
    set1.setLabel(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("<h1> Zenith Bitcoin</h1> ")));

    set1.setCircleRadius(4f);
    set1.setDrawCircleHole(true);
    set1.setValueTextSize(9f);
    set1.setDrawFilled(true);
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_red);
    if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK)>17)
        set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets

    // create a data object with the datasets
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

    mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);

    //mChart.setViewPortOffsets(55f, 25f, 115f, 125f);
    mChart.setDrawMarkers(true);
    //mChart.setExtraOffsets(10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);

    mChart.getAxisRight().setXOffset(15);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setXOffset(15);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);

    CustomMarkerView mv = new CustomMarkerView (Dashboard.this, R.layout.custom_marker_view_layout);
    mChart.setMarkerView(mv);
    // set data
    mChart.clear();
    mChart.setData(data);
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug that because its not error of library but of values when you provide for entries. Make sure `SplashScreen.arrayListPrice.get(i)` is not `null`.

Comment: already tried still throws exception 
on

-com.github.mikephil.charting.data.DataSet.getEntryForIndex(DataSet.java:286)